# SwiftUI closure capturing @State breaks memoization?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Any swiftui invalidation expert?

I'm aware the view structs initializers are supposed to be called all the time, but the body only when the inputs change = a swiftui optimization

```
struct FooView : View {
    let counter: Int
    let onOpenFaq: () -> Void
    @State showDialog = false

    var body: some View {
        ...
        .sheet(isPresented: $showDialog) {
            SimpleSheetContent(
                title: "Bar",
                message: "Bar messagge",
                onPositiveClick: onOpenFaq,
                onNegativeClick: {
                    showDialog = false <------------------
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

struct SimpleSheetContent : View {
    let title: String
    let message: String
    let onPositiveClick: () -> Void
    let onNegativeClick: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        let _ = print("SimpleSheetContent body")
        VStack {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

What I notice, **if the click closures  writes to `showDialog` in such way, then the `body` of `SimpleSheetContent` is invoked** everytime when `counter` changes - a unrelated change

Why is this? is such closure not considered "stable"?

//

If write the closure in this way

```
onNegativeClick: { [$showFoo] in
  $showFoo.wrappedValue = false
}
```

then the sheet body is not invoked, and everything appears as expected

**Is this a bug? Or am I using it wrong?**

Comment: `FooView` is a struct, which means it is a value type and therefore immutable. The only way `counter` can change is for the struct to be thrown away and a new struct created with the new value of `counter`.

Comment: excuse my ignorance but how is that causing the issue? Issue is View's `body` is invoked, which should only be invoked, if inputs change = memoization..no?

Comment: FYI `body` is called when a state is set if it was previously read, i.e. the getter was called. And `$` is sugar for `Binding(get:{} set:{})` so that does not count as a read, you would need `{ [showFoo]` to force a read  if it wasn’t read already.

Answer (score 6):

When `counter` changes, SwiftUI has to call `FooView`’s `body` again. `FooView`’s `body` creates a new closure each time it is called, and passes the new closure to `SimpleSheetContent.init` as the `onNegativeClick` argument.

SwiftUI then compares the new `SimpleSheetContent` value to the prior `SimpleSheetContent` value. Since `SimpleSheetContent` is not `Equatable`, SwiftUI compares it member by member.

Since closures are never `Equatable`, SwiftUI’s only option is to compare the old `onNegativeClick` closure to the new `onNegativeClick` closure byte by byte. A closure is stored as two pointers: a pointer to machine code, and a pointer to the closure’s capture block, which is usually a value on the heap.

The old closure and the new closure each have their own capture blocks at different addresses on the heap, so they will never compare equal. Therefore SwiftUI will have to ask `SimpleSheetContent` for its body every time.

Note that SwiftUI does not know how big the capture block is, or even if it’s truly a pointer to a capture block. (The Swift ABI only requires that it be something that can be passed to `swift_retain` and `swift_release`, and there are other things like tagged values that those functions understand.) So SwiftUI cannot compare the capture blocks bytewise.

### UPDATE

Your `onNegativeClick` closure only dismisses the sheet. You can get the same behavior without creating a closure.

One way is to use the `dismiss` property of the environment:

```
struct SimpleSheetContent : View {
    let title: String
    let message: String
    let onPositiveClick: () -> Void

    // Replace onNegativeClick with this property: <-----------------------
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    var body: some View {
        let _ = print("SimpleSheetContent body")
        VStack {
            ...

            // Use it like this: <----------------------------
            Button("Cancel") { dismiss() }
        }
    }
}
```

In my small amount of testing, this prevents SwiftUI from calling `body` repeatedly.

Another way is to pass in a `Binding` to `showDialog`:

```
struct SimpleSheetContent : View {
    let title: String
    let message: String
    let onPositiveClick: () -> Void

    // Replace onNegativeClick with this property: <-----------------------
    @Binding var showDialog: Bool

    var body: some View {
        let _ = print("SimpleSheetContent body")
        VStack {
            ...

            // Use it like this: <----------------------------
            Button("Cancel") {
                showDialog = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my small amount of testing, this also prevents SwiftUI from calling `body` repeatedly.

Comment: Great insight @rob-mayoff. Doesi it then however mean every capturing closure breaks memoization & I should use something else?. Or is this considered fine? Or should I make my Views Equatable & ommit the closure in the equals function?

Comment: You should make sure it's causing performance problems before worrying about it. You should definitely not ignore the closure if you conform to `Equatable`. Note that conforming to `Equatable` doesn't do anything unless you also apply the `.equatable()` modifier.

Comment: I've updated my answer with two ways to avoid creating the `onNegativeClick` closure.

Comment: Well, mostly asking about the correct contract. Would you write code like that?